# What happens if a conditional isn't supplied to a For Loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, int

Consider this snippet:

```
int numbers[9] = {5, 2, 78, 23, 8, 9, 3, 12, 97};
int arrLength = (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; arrLength; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
}
```

I'd given an array length as the second parameter to the loop, but gave it no conditional for when to stop. The out gave the 9 numbers inside my array and then continued. Here is an example of the program output. The program output easily over 100 digits in this manner. Can anyone explain what is at play?

[image]

Comment: You provided a conditional; you just used a shorthand for `arrLength != 0`.  Omitting a conditional would look like: `for (int i = 0; ; i++)`.  That is an infinite loop; the missing condition is treated as always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the condition *is* supplied.

```
 for(int i = 0; arrLength; i++)
```

is the same as

```
for(int i = 0; arrLength != 0; i++)
```

In other words, the controlling expression (a.k.a. condition check) should evaluate to TRUE for continuing the execution of the loop body.

From `C11`, chapter 6.8.5, P4

> *An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to 0. [...]*

and, footnote 158, `for` loop

> *[...]the controlling expression, expression-2, specifies an evaluation made before each iteration, such that execution of the loop continues until the expression compares equal to 0; [...]*

In case the condition is **not** supplied, it's considered as a non-zero (always true value).

Chapter 6.8.5.3, Paragraph 2

> *Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.*

Comment: It seems I'd created an infinite loop. But the program does terminate eventually. Is this due to memory being exhausted on the machine? My task manager doesn't show any memory spike.

Comment: @KeplerIO There's much more, uncontrolled increment of the counter will cause overflow, and given the counter is of type signed integer, it'll cause undefined behaviour.